# how show css in header with response?

Tags: css, cakephp, header, response

i have cms on cakephp
i have my css of my site as a text in component
how to attach this on page as a css file?
my cose is :

```
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
$this->Controller->response->sharable(true, 86400);
$this->Controller->response->expires('+1 days');
$this->Controller->response->type('text/css');
$this->Controller->response->body($css);
echo $css
```

but show on page html cod and css together on page

Comment: I cannot understand your English, please try to reformulate your question.

Comment: I am completely on Jeroen Noten's side. Only things I can tell you ad-hoc: Don't use ob_start in a Component. Don't echo in a component. Also if you want to have a dynamic CSS I would recommend using [HtmlHelper::style](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html)

Comment: all my css cod is in variable, i want to use this like normall css file like this : <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />. this variable is in my component. In fact, I have a component This component read all style files and I keep them until they are combine

Comment: Why have you got CSS in a component? This belongs in a CSS file within your webroot that you'd include using `$this->Html->css()` in your Views. Your question is really not clear. Please look at it again and update it with more details of what you're trying to do. Otherwise no one is going to be able to help you as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

all my css code is in variable, i want to use this like normall css file like this : . this variable is in my component. In fact, I have a component This component read all style files and I keep them until they are combine